# How to dynamically populate display objects in Angular JS based on properties from the JSON object.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am reading the below json value from a module.js

```
.controller('home.person',['$scope','$filter','personResource',function($scope,$filter,personResource) {

$scope.searchPerson = function() {

var params = $scope.search || {};

params.skip=0;
params.take =10;

      $scope.personDetails =
            {
                "apiversion": "0.1",
                "code": 200,
                "status": "OK",   
                "mydata": {

                        "myrecords": [
                           {
                               "models": [
                                  {
                                      "name": "Selva",
                                      "dob": "10/10/1981"
                                  }
                               ],
                               "Address1": "ABC Street",
                               "Address2": "Apt 123",
                               "City": "NewCity1",
                               "State": "Georgia"                       
                           },

                           {
                               "models": [
                                  {
                                      "name": "Kumar",
                                      "dob": "10/10/1982"
                                  }
                               ],
                                "Address1": "BCD Street",
                               "Address2": "Apt 345",
                               "City": "NewCity2",
                               "State": "Ohio",
                               "Country":"USA"

                           },
                           {
                                "models": [
                                  {
                                      "name": "Pranav",
                                      "dob": "10/10/1983"
                                  }
                               ],
                                "Address1": "EFG Street",
                               "Address2": "Apt 678",
                               "City": "NewCity3",
                               "State": "NewYork",
                               "Country":"USA",
                               "Zipcode" :"123456"
                           }
                        ]                  
                }    
            }
}

}])
```

Now i am able to statically build the UX. But my each record set's key value pair count is different. So i want to build my html dynamically as per the current record set's count.Country & Zipcode is not exist in all records so i need to build dynamically the build and populate the html output.Most of the time, my json output is dynamic. Instead of persondetails, i may get the json output of a product details instead of PersonDetails.

```
<div   ng-show="personDetails.mydata.myrecords.length > 0"  ng-repeat="recordSingle in personDetails.mydata.myrecords">


                 <div >

                        <span >Address1: {{recordSingle.Address1}}</span>

                          <span >Address2: {{recordSingle.Address2}}</span>
                      <span>City: {{recordSingle.City}}</span>
                       <span>State: {{recordSingle.State}}</span>
                        <span>Country: {{recordSingle.Country}}</span>
                          <span>Zipcode: {{recordSingle.Zipcode}}</span>

                      </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Update #1: updated based on revised comments to question]

[Update #2: fixed typos in function and included plunkr]

I now understand that you want to dynamically build the display objects based on properties from the JSON object. In this case, I would iterate through the properties of the object. I would use a function to produce this array of properties for each object so that you can filter out any prototype chains. I would also remove out any unwanted propoerties, such as the internal `$$hashKey` and perhaps the array objects e.g.

In your controller:

```
$scope.getPropertyNames = getPropertyNames;

function getPropertyNames(obj) {
  var props = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !angular.isArray(obj[key]) && key !== '$$hashKey') {
      props.push(key);
    }
  }

  return props;
}
```

Then in your HTML view:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in personDetails.mydata.myrecords">
  <div ng-repeat="prop in getPropertyNames(record)">
    <span ng-bind="prop"></span>: <span ng-bind="record[prop]"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works for me... see [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/I2m0YlJ1vtfTnmUxKO3C/preview). It is displaying each of the properties of the object in the array dynamically (you could have any property in the object). Is this not what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for your time and help. I have updated my question with original controller code. Can you please have a look and let me know still i need to create another function to iterate the properties? Kindly advice.

Comment: @selva, did you try again after my update (with included plnkr)?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `ng-if` statement, for the optional `span` elements:

```
<span ng-if="recordSingle.Address1">Address1: {{recordSingle.Address1}}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. Most of the time, my json output is  dynamic. Instead of persondetails, i may get the json output of a product details instead of PersonDetails. So i can't do this if validation since i am not sure about the output field names in the json.